# Plotting Raster on top of Vector layer in Mapview - R

Tags: r, mapview

I am wondering if it is possible to display a raster layer on top of a vector layer when two mapview maps are combined without using `alpha.regions = 0` to make the polygon fill transparent. So far I was not able to success.
A small reproducible example where, in both cases, polygon is placed on top of raster avoiding proper visualization of the raster layer.

```
library(plainview)    
mapview(poppendorf[[1]]) + mapview(franconia)
```

Results on:
[image]

And the following code resulting on the same output.

```
mapview(franconia) + mapview(poppendorf[[1]])
```

[image]